# Create a Ruby Hash out of an xml string with the 'ox' gem

Tags: ruby, xml

I am currently trying to create a hash out of an xml documen, with the help of the ox gem

Input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<expense>
  <payee>starbucks</payee>
  <amount>5.75</amount>
  <date>2017-06-10</date>
</expense>
```

with the following ruby/ox code:

```
doc = Ox.parse(xml)
plist = doc.root.nodes
```

I get the following output:

```
=> [#<Ox::Element:0x00007f80d985a668 @value="payee", @attributes={}, @nodes=["starbucks"]>, #<Ox::Element:0x00007f80d9839198 @value="amount", @attributes={}, @nodes=["5.75"]>, #<Ox::Element:0x00007f80d9028788 @value="date", @attributes={}, @nodes=["2017-06-10"]>]
```

The output I want is a hash in the format:

```
{'payee'  => 'Starbucks',
'amount' => 5.75,
'date'   => '2017-06-10'}
```

to save in my sqllite database. 
How can I transform the objects array into a hash like above. 

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs suggest you can use the following:

```
require 'ox'

xml = %{
<top name="sample">
  <middle name="second">
    <bottom name="third">Rock bottom</bottom>
  </middle>
</top>
}

puts Ox.load(xml, mode: :hash)
puts Ox.load(xml, mode: :hash_no_attrs)

#{:top=>[{:name=>"sample"}, {:middle=>[{:name=>"second"}, {:bottom=>[{:name=>"third"}, "Rock bottom"]}]}]}
#{:top=>{:middle=>{:bottom=>"Rock bottom"}}}
```

I'm not sure that's exactly what you're looking for though.

Otherwise, it really depends on the methods available on the `Ox::Element` instances in the array.

From [the docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/ohler55/ox/Ox/Element), it looks like there are two handy methods here: you can use `[]` and `text`.

Therefore, I'd use [reduce](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/reduce) to coerce the array into the hash format you're looking for, using something like the following:

```
ox_nodes = [#<Ox::Element:0x00007f80d985a668 @value="payee", @attributes={}, @nodes=["starbucks"]>, #<Ox::Element:0x00007f80d9839198 @value="amount", @attributes={}, @nodes=["5.75"]>, #<Ox::Element:0x00007f80d9028788 @value="date", @attributes={}, @nodes=["2017-06-10"]>]

ox_nodes.reduce({}) do |hash, node|
  hash[node['@value']] = node.text
  hash
end
```

I'm not sure whether `node['@value']` will work, so you might need to experiment with that - otherwise perhaps `node.instance_variable_get('@value')` would do it.

[node.text](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/ohler55/ox/Ox/Element#text-instance_method) does the following, which sounds about right:

> Returns the first String in the elements nodes array or nil if there is no String node.

N.B. I prefer to tidy the `reduce` block a little using `tap`, something like the following:

```
ox_nodes.reduce({}) do |hash, node|
  hash.tap { |h| h[node['@value']] = node.text } 
end
```

Hope that helps - let me know how you get on!

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. All  of what you said is right and helped me lot. In the second example it has to be node.text instead of node.string since ox::Element only has a #text method. Concerning the "docs" of Ox. For a newbie like me who is learning ruby and rails for two months now with no prior background in computer Science it is very hard to read the Ox documentation. For Instance how did you come up with the mode: :hash argument. i studied the load method all day yesterday before posting here and it said:  :mode (:object|:generic|:limited) — format expected

Comment: I wonder how did You know that You can use :hash as a mode. Answering that would really help me to not get stuck with reading docs like the Ox one for days and still not having a clue what i can do with it.

Comment: The next problem i have o solve with the OX gem is to turn the resulting hash back into an xml. Do you have any idea how I could do that?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, glad I could help :) I'm away for Christmas for a bit now - I seem to recall seeing the docs referencing accepting the ':[]' method, which led me to believe it would work as a hash. For your second problem, I'd suggest creating another question (if you haven't already), but it might be worth looking at the Savin gem, which is a diamond when it comes to working with XML!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to the question in my last comment by myself:

```
def create_xml(expense)
    Ox.default_options=({:with_xml => false})
    doc = Ox::Document.new(:version => '1.0')
    expense.each do |key, value|
        e = Ox::Element.new(key)
        e << value
        doc << e
    end
    Ox.dump(doc)
end
```

The next question would be how can i transform the value of the amount key from a string to an integer befopre saving it to the database